# Add NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController to the left of the titlebar/toolbar

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller

I have implemented a unified titlebar/toolbar and now would like to add two buttons to the bar. They need to be located at the far left, just right of the stoplight buttons. I'm creating a toolbar that's very similar to System Preferences.

I have looked at the API for adding `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` and the only valid properties for `layoutAttribute` are `NSLayoutAttributeRight` (adds the view to the far right of the toolbar) and `NSLayoutAttributeBottom` which essentially places the view underneath the unified toolbar in its own toolbar.

I want neither of those options, so how would one add a bunch of buttons to the very left of the unified toolbar?

[image]

Comment: did you ever figure this out? is the toolbar compatible with titlebaracessoryviewcontroller even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible in OS X 10.11. Quoting from the header file:

> For applications linked on Mac OS 10.11 or later, `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` is also supported; placing the item on the left side of the window (adjacent and to the right of the close/minimize/maximize buttons).

Comment: I think this is such a cool UI element, but only on 10.11 ??, why not present on at least 10.10 ...

Answer (score 3):

It is actually a lot easier to archive this:

Just add a toolbar to your window using the Interface Builder and set the title visibility to hidden:

```
[window setTitleVisibility:NSWindowTitleHidden];
```

Comment: Right but this only centers the stoplight buttons and hides the title text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WAYAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/weAreYeah/WAYAppStoreWindow/) on GitHub to do this. I created a fork of the [WAYWindow](https://github.com/dbrisinda/WAYWindow) subproject to vertically centre the document title since this wasn't supported.